# Como agendar um agendamento com kivy

Tags: python, agendamento, kivy, clock

Estou querendo fazer com que um evento ocorra por 2 segundos na velocidade de 29/30, após 5 segundos passados desde o inicio do programa, com o seguinte código:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import *

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

stop= 0

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return LoginScreen()

    def my_callback(dt):
        global stop
        if stop == 1:
            print ('Last call of my callback, bye bye !')
            return False
        print ('My callback is called')

    def stop_my_callback(dt):
        global stop
        stop = 1

    def start_my_callback(dt):
        event = Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 29 / 30.)
        Clock.schedule_once(stop_my_callback, 2)

    Clock.schedule_once(start_my_callback, 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Porém, após 5 segundos, o console retorna:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\teste.py", line 44, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 826, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 727, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 460, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 337, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 581, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\teste.py", line 38, in start_my_callback
     event = Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 29 / 30.)
 NameError: name 'my_callback' is not defined
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao definir métodos de uma classe, o primeiro parâmetro é sempre a instância da classe sendo utilizada para chamar o método, e é passado automaticamente pelo python. Por convenção, utiliza-se o nome `self`:

```
def my_callback(self, dt):
    ...
def stop_my_callback(self, dt):
    ...
def start_my_callback(self, dt):
    ...
```

Uma das vantagens de usar classes é não precisar mais utilizar globais, evitando todas as confusões que elas podem causar. Ao invés disso, torna-se possível armazenar dados de acordo com o contexto, através de atributos da classe ou de suas instâncias. No exemplo abaixo podemos usar um atributo da instância através de `self.stop`:

```
def start_my_callback(self, dt):
    self.stop = 0
    ...

def stop_my_callback(self, dt):
    self.stop = 1

def my_callback(self, dt):
    if self.stop == 1:
        ...
```

Uma outra alteração é na hora de se referir a um método. Após a definição de uma classe, os métodos se tornam atributos das instâncias. Dessa forma, se estiver dentro de um método da classe, pode-se usar novamente o `self` para obter a referência a outro método, no exemplo o `self.my_callback`:

```
def start_my_callback(self, dt):
    self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 29 / 30.)
    Clock.schedule_once(self.stop_my_callback, 2)
```